# Bring this [prefix] to an end

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I was on the main page, and [a very poor question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441329/i-need-to-a-a-prefix-to-a-variable) was on there with a [single tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prefix/): [prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prefix). Clearly "I need to add a prefix to a variable" is a question that shouldn't exist on this site, and will probably be removed very quickly. However, the tag really stuck with me.

Checking its definition shows that it has absolutely no bearing on anything of a programming nature.

> A prefix is a part of a word attached to a beginning of a word which modifies the meaning of that stem.

Looking at the other questions with that tag, it adds absolutely nothing to the quality of the questions. No one can be an "expert" in prefixes.

Comment: It works with the [steps of the burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191).

Comment: True useless tag but is the work (>800 questions) worth it?, what actual damage does it do?, I don't really feel it creates off-topic question in itself.

Comment: @PetterFriberg In the example of the one I included, that was the only tag, and allowed them to create an off-topic question.

Comment: @krillgar still not sure, probably they would have used [tag:variables] instead, since we have few reviewers and people ready to chip in we need to concentrate our energy where it make a difference for the future.

Comment: @PetterFriberg But at least [tag:variables] has the ambiguous warning. [tag:prefix] isn't even ambiguous.

Comment: Going along with the "work arugment" by @PetterFriberg, i wanted to also provide *some* sort of "loose reason" why this could stay. Sometimes people in linguistics or sentiment programming (thinking of [`nltk`](http://www.nltk.org/) for python in particular). determine the meaning, or root of a word can be done with prefixes.